# Is decentralized communication between 3+ computers in a network possible in python?

Tags: python, network-programming, gossip

So I've been racking my brain trying to implement a system in which computers on a network (where there are always three or more computers on the network) are able to asynchronously communicate with each other by sending each other data.

So far, all I've been able to find as far as solutions go is sockets--which, to my knowledge, requires a client and a server script. My first problem is that I'd like to remove any client or server roles since all of the computers on the network are decentralized and running the same script concurrently without a server. Secondly, all of the computers are sending other nodes (chosen at random) sensor data from a specific point in time. If, for example, I have 4 computers on the network and--since they're all running the same script--they decide to send their data to another computer at the same time, wouldn't that cause a wait lock since all of the nodes are trying to communicate with another computer, but those computers are unable to accept the connection because they're also trying to send data?

I've considered using multithreading to run my begin_sync and wait_sync functions concurrently, but I'm not sure whether or not that would work. Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas for solutions that I could look into?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Sockets are how all communication is done. It doesn't have to be client-server, thats just the most widely used paradigm. Peer-to-peer is a perfectly viable option for many projects, including yours. As for wait lock, you don't need to use the same socket for sending and receiving. I would advice against it. Try to make a connection and if the receive is busy, just wait and retry. Without code I can't really be more specific. But you have options. I'd look into peer-to-peer solutions for ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per NotTheBatman's response, I was able to get this to work using sockets on multiple ports. As far as how I handled being able to wait for sensor data and query other nodes, I simply used multithreading with great success.